# Is there a good way to connect to a SQL Server using Windows authentication from a Sharepoint 2010 event hander?

Tags: event-handlers, sql

Inherited some legacy code that makes use of SQL authentication which I want to eliminate.

When I tried using Windows auth, the connection seemed to be getting created using ANONYMOUS LOGIN. is there a way to connect using a Windows account instead?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following connection string:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Source:

[ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: That may work, but another aim is to not store the password in plain text anywhere. I'll give this a try on Monday as well..

Comment: Than you can store the password somewhere encrypted and decrypt it in code, than append to connection string..